# How to shuffle my Array or String list in a more readable way?

Tags: php, arrays, string, random, shuffle

Imagine you want to have a very readable, easily editable list of items, separated by comma's only, and then echo 3 random items from that list. Array or string doesnt matter. For now, I got the following working (Thanks webbiedave!)

```
$fruits = array('Mango', 'Banana', 'Cucumber', 'Pear', 'Peach', 'Coconut');

$keys = array_rand($fruits, 3);   // get 3 random keys from your array
foreach ($keys as $key) {         // cycle through the keys to get the values
    echo $fruits[$key] . "<br/>";
}
```

Outputs:

```
Coconut
Pear
Banana
```

Only thing unsolved here is that the list is not so readable as I wished:
Personally, I very much prefer the input list to be without the quotes e.g. `Mango` as opposed to `'Mango'` , meaning preferably like so:

`(Mango, Banana, Cucumber, Pear, Peach, Suthern Melon, Coconut)`

Is this easily possible? Thanks very much for your input.

Comment: If you are talking about `array(....)`, then there is no way to change this. Strings have to be in quotes in PHP. Everything else won't be more readable or maintainable...

Comment: There is no "more correct" way to initialize an array in PHP than the array of quoted strings you provide. If you want different syntax, switch to a different language. Try Ruby: `fruits = %w{Mango Banana Cucumber Pear Peach Suthern\ Melon Coconut}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$input = explode(',', 'Mango, Banana, Cucumber, Pear, Peach, Suthern Melon, Coconut');
$input = array_map('trim', $input);
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea! Is there any performance penalty when 1000 items are in this list, as opposed to an array, with 20% more characters sinces `'Mango'`  is 20% more than `Mango` ?

Comment: An array definition is most likely faster and certainly the preferred solution if the items will be hardcoded anyway. If you are lazy, you can have PHP generate the array for you from a string: `<?php var_export(array_map('trim', explode(',', 'your, list, here'))); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Not without going against PHP standards.

You could define constants such as

```
define(Mango, "Mango");
```

and use them in your array, but that would defeat the [naming conventions of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php), as constants should be all UPPERCASE

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an **editable** list, I suggest to create a configuration file and read the list from there.

For example, you could use [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaml) and the [symfony YAML parser](http://components.symfony-project.org/yaml/). Your list would look like this:

```
- Mango
- Banana
- Cucumber
- Pear
- Peach
- Coconut
```

This would be a better separation of your code and data. It would also be more maintainable in the long run, as you don't have to touch the actual code when adding or removing elements.

Or of course in your case, you could just have a simple text file with one entry per line and read the file into an array.

If you are worried about performance, you could serialize the generated array to disk or something like that.