# How to shuffle string?

Tags: php

I want to shuffle a sentence.

Original:

```
I LOVE YOU
```

Shuffle:

```
LOVE I YOU
```

Or

```
I YOU LOVE
```

**How do I do that?**

Comment: Well, how would you approach it by yourself? You could check out [explode()](http://php.net/explode) and [shuffle()](http://php.net/shuffle).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is not a valid question here. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Here's a few posts that might help you solve your problem, and give an idea of what kind of effort is expected on your part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155166/how-to-shuffle-and-echo-3-random-words-out-of-a-string, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156428/how-to-shuffle-echo-5-random-elements-from-a-string, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857185/how-to-shuffle-my-array-or-string-list-in-a-more-readable-way, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380660/get-a-certain-number-of-random-words-from-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a function:

```
function shuffle_string($original, $split_char = ' '){
    $str_array = explode($split_char, $original);
    shuffle($str_array);
    $shuffle_str = '';
    foreach ($str_array as $item) {
        $shuffle_str .= $item . $split_char;
    }
    return trim($shuffle_str, $split_char);
}

$a = 'I love you';
echo shuffle_string($a);
```

Comment: You can simplify the last part with `return join($split_char, $str_array);`